Using .ttf font files in CustomTkinter / Python
I have built a Python user interface using the CustomTkinter library. I am using the 'Inter' font family and it works well on my machine, since I have the fonts installed.
However, I am trying to distribute the app to other users using the PyInstaller library, and it looks like if the other user does not have the font family installed on their machine, the fonts are not displayed correctly.
I've tried using the pyglet library to load the fonts, but that didn't fix it. How can I make sure that the users are seeing the same fonts as I do, without them having to install those fonts?

Note: I cannot use any package installers (InnoSetup/InstallForge), the app needs to be distributed using PyInstaller.

This is my main.py file where I've tried the pyglet method:
from components import App
import pyglet
from functions import resource_path

# Register the fonts
font_files = [
    resource_path("_internal\\assets\\fonts\\Inter-Bold.ttf"),
    resource_path("_internal\\assets\\fonts\\Inter-Regular.ttf"),
    resource_path("_internal\\assets\\fonts\\Inter-SemiBold.ttf"),
    resource_path("_internal\\assets\\fonts\\Inter-ExtraBold.ttf"),
]

def main():
    for font_file in font_files:
        pyglet.font.add_file(font_file)
    # Display the app interface
    App().mainloop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()


Take a look at this post.

This question may help to fix the issue on not loading the font.

Note also that you need to embed the font files into the generated executable.

@acw1668 I've added the below line and it worked, thank you.
pyglet.options['win32_gdi_font'] = True
